# Redirect location 'about:blank' has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, redirect, cors, axios

I'm trying to access facebooks graph API using axios in a react component.

When the component mounts I get my facebook access token and call

`` axios
.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendsaccess_token=${token}&fields=name,id,picture`)
.then(result => this.setState({ friends: result.data.data }))
.catch(error => console.log(error)) ``

It works on development.

I deploy the app to firebase and it works on my computer. If I try it on someone else' computer I get teh following error in the console.

`Failed to load https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token={token}&fields=name,id,picture: Redirect from 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token={token}&fields=name,id,picture' has been blocked by CORS policy: Redirect location 'about:blank' has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.`

I can't seem to find any documentations about CORS redirect location being 'about:blank'. Does anyone know what this means or how I can fix it?

Comment: Also if I just enter the url in my browser with the access token it works fine. Returns a json object with all the data.

Comment: `/me/friendsaccess_token=` - that’s a typo here, I presume, but not in your actual code?

Comment: No, no, I just cut the actual token out incase it would be a problme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a chrome extension clash issue. The problem only occurs ion chrome and disabled extensions solves the problem. Check your extensions.